# Activation email in vb.net identity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I hope someone can shed some light for me, I have an application that users can register and have un-commented lines in the register.aspx.vb file to allow for email.

```
   Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userName As String = Email.Text
    Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
    Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
    Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = userName, .Email = userName}
    Dim result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text)
    If result.Succeeded Then
        ' For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        Dim code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id)
        Dim callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request)
        manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """>here</a>.")

        signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent := False, rememberBrowser := False)
        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
    Else
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is though, that I need to add email settings similar to that at http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity#email but not sure how to call this, and does this need to go in the Identity.config under EmailService???  Do I need to add something to the web.config????

Answer (score 0):

Add the details to your web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from=“-your-sending-email-address-">
            <network defaultCredentials="false" host=“-mail.example.com-" password=“—password-" userName=“—email—account-" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

More information:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx